# CakePHP find joined records with conditions on each table

Tags: cakephp, join, cakephp-2.0

I want to see all the records from a join, setting a `WHERE` condition on each side of the join.

For example, I have `LOAN` and `BORROWER` (joined on `borrower.id = loan.borrower_id`). I want the records where LOAN.field = 123 and `BORROWER.field = 'abc'`.

The answers here ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083494/cakephp-multiple-model-conditions-in-find-with-habtm), for example) seem to say that I should use Containable.

I tried that. Here's my code:

```
$stuff = $this->Borrower->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Borrower.email LIKE' => $this->request->data['email'] // 'abc'
    ),
'contain'=>array(
    'Loan' => array(
        'conditions' => array('Loan.id' => $this->request->data['loanNumber']) // 123
        )
    )
));
```

I expected to have a single result because in my data, there is only one joined record with both of those conditions. Instead, I get two results,

Result 1 is `{Borrower: {field:abc, LOAN: {field: 123} }` // correct

Result 2 is `{Borrower: {field:abc, LOAN: {NULL} }` // incorrect

When I look at the SQL that CakePHP used, I don't see a join. What I see is two separate queries:

Query 1: `SELECT * from BORROWER // (yielding 2 IDs)`,

Query 2: `SELECT * FROM LOAN WHERE borrower_id in (IDs)`

This is not what I want. I want to join the tables, then apply my conditions. I could easily write the SQL query, but am trying to do it the Cake way since we've adopted that framework.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to do something like this:

```
    $options['conditions'] = array(
           'Borrower.email LIKE' => $this->request->data['email'] // 'abc',
           'loan.field' => '123' )

    $options['joins'] = array(
        array('table' => 'loans',
              'alias' => 'loan',
              'type' => 'INNER',
              'conditions' => array(
                    'borrower.id = loan.borrower_id')
                )
            );

    $options['fields'] = array('borrower.email', 'loan.field');

    $test = $this->Borrower->find('all', $options);
```

You should see a SQL statement like:

```
SELECT borrower.email, loan.field
FROM borrowers AS borrower
INNER JOIN loans AS loan
    ON borrower.id = loan.borrower_id
    AND loan.field = '123'
WHERE borrower.email = 'abc'
```

Your results will be in an array

```
{Borrower: {field:abc} LOAN: {field: 123} }
```

You will find more information in this [document](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables).

Answer (score 3):

I think I'll accept Jose's answer because it's exactly what I want. But I did notice that I didn't need any fancy tricks -- no joins or contains -- if I used the *other* model as my starting point.

A `Borrower` `hasMany` `Loan`s, and a `Loan` `belongsTo` a `Borrower`. Using `Loan` as my model, Cake will automatically join the tables, but not using `Borrower`.

```
$this->Loan->find('all', array( // Not $this->Borrower->find() !
'conditions' => array(
    'Borrower.field' => 'abc',
    'Loan.field' => 123
)
));
```