# CakePHP query preparation with join statement and subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I', learning CakePHP, but I have a great problem with operating with more complex database queries.
So I would like to execute that kind of query:

```
SELECT p.name, b.value
FROM books b LEFT JOIN projects p
ON b.project_id=p.id
WHERE b.created=
(SELECT max(b.created) FROM books b WHERE b.user_id=1)
AND b.user_id=1
GROUP BY p.name
```

Can anybody help me write this using cakePHP mechanism for preparing queries?

Comment: Are you trying to use the find() method on a Book model with this SQL statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be something similar to this, assuming Book e Project are in relationship (`Book` belongsTo `Project`)

```
$this->Book->find
(
    'all',
    array
    (
        'fields' => array('Book.value', 'Project.name'),
        'conditions' => array
        (
            'Book.created IN (SELECT MAX(Book.created) FROM books Book WHERE Book.user_id = 1)',
            'Book.user_id' => 1
        ),
        'group' => 'Project.name'
    )
);
```

Comment: Great, I think this is something I was looking for :) Thx

Answer (score 0):

Use IN clause.

```
   SELECT p.name, b.value
   FROM books b 
   LEFT JOIN projects p ON b.project_id=p.id
   WHERE b.created IN (SELECT max(created) FROM books  WHERE user_id=1)
   AND b.user_id=1
   GROUP BY p.name
```

Answer (score 0):

if Book and Projects are Models, you can use Book model to directly join using the CakePHP function, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16286735/2858188