# Get last comment for each chat room through GROUP By not working in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a simple chat system. In that chat system user can see comments that has sent to him. I want to show only the last (one) comment per chat room but it's not working with my Query. So please help me to gain a proper result

Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE  users (
  `user_id` int,
  `user_name` varchar(55)
);

CREATE TABLE  chat_room (
  `chat_room_id` int,
  `description` varchar(55)
);
CREATE TABLE chat_room_comments (
  `comment_id` int,
  `chat_room_id` int,
  `sender_id` int,
  `comment` varchar(55),  
  `send_to` int,
  `read_status` tinyint
);
```

And Data:

```
INSERT INTO users
  (`user_id`, `user_name`)
VALUES
  (1, 'The Rock'),
  (2, 'Dwayne'),
  (3, 'Johnson')
;

INSERT INTO chat_room
  (`chat_room_id`, `description`)
VALUES
  (1, 'Room 1'),
  (2, 'Room 2'),
  (3, 'Room 3')
;

INSERT INTO chat_room_comments
  (`comment_id`,`chat_room_id`, `sender_id`,`comment`, `send_to`,`read_status`)
VALUES
  (1,1,2, 'Room 1 Hello The Rock',1,0),
  (2,1,1, 'Hello Dwayne',2,0),
  (3,1,3, 'Hello Dwayne',2,0),
  (4,2,1, 'Hello Johnson',3,0),
  (5,2,3, 'Hello Dwayne',2,0), 
  (6,2,2, 'Room 2 Hello The Rock',1,0),   
  (7,3,1, 'Hello Johnson',3,0), 
  (8,3,3, 'Room 3 Hello The Rock',1,0),    
  (9,3,3, 'Room 3 Hello The Rock',1,0),
  (10,3,2, 'Hello Johnson',3,0)       
;
```

My Query ( Not Working Properly as my requirement ):

```
SELECT * FROM chat_room CR 
LEFT JOIN chat_room_comments CRC ON CRC.chat_room_id = CR.chat_room_id 
LEFT JOIN users U ON U.user_id = CRC.sender_id
WHERE 
 CRC.send_to = 1
GROUP BY CRC.comment_id
ORDER BY CRC.comment_id DESC
```

Query Result:

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a14391/9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to get last comment_id per chat_room_id

```
SELECT chat_room_id, MAX(comment_id) as last_comment_id FROM chat_room_comments 
WHERE send_to = 1 GROUP BY chat_room_id
```

and then use this results to JOIN other data

```
SELECT CR.*, CRC.* , U.*
FROM  chat_room_comments CRC 
JOIN (
    SELECT chat_room_id, MAX(comment_id) as last_comment_id FROM chat_room_comments 
    WHERE send_to = 1 GROUP BY chat_room_id
) LCRC ON CRC.chat_room_id = LCRC.chat_room_id AND CRC.comment_id = LCRC.last_comment_id
JOIN chat_room CR ON CRC.chat_room_id = CR.chat_room_id 
LEFT JOIN users U ON U.user_id = CRC.sender_id
ORDER BY CRC.comment_id DESC
```

or

```
SELECT CR.*, CRC.* , U.*
FROM  chat_room_comments CRC 
JOIN chat_room CR ON CRC.chat_room_id = CR.chat_room_id 
LEFT JOIN users U ON U.user_id = CRC.sender_id
WHERE CRC.comment_id IN (SELECT MAX(comment_id) as last_comment_id FROM chat_room_comments 
    WHERE send_to = 1 GROUP BY chat_room_id)
ORDER BY CRC.comment_id DESC
```

Comment: xto bro its working but i have to convert this query to cakephp format

Comment: you can use other way i've just added above and try to use this trick [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245674/cakephp-query-preparation-with-join-statement-and-subquery) to create IN condition in cakephp